# Django NoReverseMatch Error from Template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have in app_main/templates/app/detail.html:

```
{% for i in user_items %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'app_main:update_last_clicked' username=username url=i.url %}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have in app_main/urls.py:

```
    url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>[.]*)/$', views.update_last_clicked, name='update_last_clicked'),
```

And I have in app_main/views.py:

```
def update_last_clicked(request, username, url):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    user.item_set.get(url=url).last_clicked += 1
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

I get the NoReverseMatch Error as follows:

```
NoReverseMatch at /app_main/u/florin/
Reverse for 'update_last_clicked' with keyword arguments '{u'username': u'florin', u'url': u'fg'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'app_main/u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>[.]*)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/app_main/u/florin/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'update_last_clicked' with keyword arguments '{u'username': u'florin', u'url': u'fg'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'app_main/u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>[.]*)/$']
Exception Location: /Users/f/Desktop/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
```

Python Executable:  /Users/f/Desktop/django/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10

With more:

```
In template /Users/f/Desktop/django/app/app_main/templates/app_main/detail.html, error at line 5
Reverse for 'update_last_clicked' with keyword arguments '{u'username': u'florin', u'url': u'fg'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'app_main/u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>[.]*)/$']
```

I don't understand what's going on: I just want to update an attribute in the item object that is clicked, but with this code added, it gives me this error when I just go to the detail.html view, whose urlpattern is `url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),`
The complete urlpatterns in app_main/urls.py is:

```
app_name = 'app_main'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/add_item/$', views.add_item, name='add_item'),
url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>[.]*)/$', views.update_last_clicked, name='update_last_clicked'),
]
```

For reference, app/urls.py has `url(r'^app_main/', include('app_main.urls')),`

I essentially want to pass the item clicked to a view without a form. I figure since I just need to pass the item's url attribute, I can append it to the current url to pass it. Am I wrong? Do I have to use an AJAX call or a form?

FIX: I kept changing things and what worked was just changing `url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>[.]*)/$', views.update_last_clicked, name='update_last_clicked'),` to `url(r'^u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/update_last_clicked/(?P<url>.*)/$', views.update_last_clicked, name='update_last_clicked'),`. Does anyone understand why simply taking out the grouping brackets changes this?

Comment: @whoever commented before, I added the project's complete urls

Comment: yeah, actually, I needed to know how you've included the app's urls. The last line gave it. I didn't see that before.

Comment: The pattern shown in the error is not the same as the one you have shown here; yours has named arguments, the one in the error does not.

Comment: I see them as both having the named arguments username and url. Can you paste the portion you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It is the same!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a namespace to the app.
For eg -

`url(r'^app_main/', include('app_main.urls', namespace='app_main'))`

Similary, for all other apps for which you are going to reverse based on app and url name.

You can also do this by mentioning the `app_name` in `app_main/urls.py` like this -

```
app_name = 'app_main'
urlpatterns = [...]
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error after adding namespace to the include function in the url function. I already had app_name; I should've included it—I'll do that now.